# Conda Env: Python not loading Tensorflow module from Env packages

Tags: python, tensorflow

After installing and uninstalling tensorflow, trying to get the GPU to be recognized in this particular Conda env, I noticed that the tensorflow module isn't being called from the env packages.

```
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import tensorflow
/home/fosa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>>> print(matplotlib.__file__)
/home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/newTensor/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py
>>> print(tensorflow.__file__)
/home/fosa/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
>>>
```

Any idea how to fix this? My other Env which uses python=2.7 doesn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the `sys.path` in python it had the global packages directory listed before the ENV directory. Putting the local anaconda env before the global package directory fixed the problem.